# 18th derivative of $\arctan(x^2)$ at point $x=0$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives

$$\frac{\mathrm d^{18}}{\mathrm dx^{18}} \arctan(x^2)$$
Without using Taylor.
I relay don't have any idea how to use General Leibniz rule or any other idea how to get result.

Comment: If you take the derivative once you get $\frac{2x}{x^4+1}$ and then you could use General Leibniz rule to find the seventeenth derivative of that ratio (which would be the 18th derivative) but that would be $\sum_{i=0}^{17}\binom{17}i(2x)^{(i)}(\frac1{x^4+1})^{(17-i)}$ which is $0$ for all $i\geq2$ so you just need to find $\sum_{i=0}^1\binom{17}i(2x)^{(i)}(\frac1{x^4+1})^{(17-i)}$ but since $x=0$ then the first term will be zero (since it has a term of $2x$) so the derivative is just the 16th derivative $\frac{34}{x^4+1}$ which is not trivial but at least we've made some progress.

Comment: I guess you can keep applying the general leibniz rule. So the first derivative of $\frac{34}{x^2+1}$ is $\frac{-136x^3}{(x^4+1)^2}$ so we are interested in the 15th derivative of that so we use general leibniz rule to find $\sum_{i=0}^{15}\binom{15}i(-136x^3)^{(i)}(\frac1{(x^4+1)^2})^{(15-i)}$ but that's zero (either because the derivative vanishes at $x=0$ or identically) for all $i$ except $i=3$ so now we just need the 12th derivative of $\binom{15}{3}*(-816)\frac1{(x^4+1)^2}$. You could probably keep reducing it this way but it is kind of tedious.

Comment: Unfortunately, it looks like it's non-zero.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**. One may write
$$\frac{\mathrm d^{18}}{\mathrm dx^{18}} \arctan(x^2)=\frac{\mathrm d^{17}}{\mathrm dx^{17}} \frac{2x}{1+x^4}$$ then, by a partial fraction decomposition, one has
$$
 \frac{2x}{1+x^4}=\frac12 \Re\left( \frac{i}{x-\frac{1-i}{\sqrt{2}}}\right)-\frac12 \Re\left( \frac{i}{x-\frac{1+i}{\sqrt{2}}}\right).
$$ Then using

> $$
> \frac{\mathrm d^n}{\mathrm dx^n} \frac{1}{x-a}=\frac{(-1)^n\:n!}{(x-a)^{n+1}}.
> $$

one finally gets

> $$
> \left.\frac{\mathrm d^{18}}{\mathrm dx^{18}} \arctan(x^2)\right|_{x=0}=711\: 374\: 956\: 192\: 000.
> $$

Comment: Can you please tell me how to fraction with i can be derivate.

Comment: @LovroSindičić Please, I don't understand your question.

Comment: How complex number i can be differentiable?

Comment: @LovroSindičić A complex number is just a **constant** number...

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Write $f(g(x))$, can you get some help expand using rules for concatenation and multiplication considering the values $f(0)$ and $g(0)$?

Comment: Can you please add some more hint.

Comment: No sorry it turned out my hint did not help very well when I tried it myself :) I can remove it if you want me to.